# Convert decimal to unicode char

Tags: android

I want to convert decimal value or hexadecimal to unicode char
I tried `Character.toString((char))` its not working all the time it return wrong result. Is there a way that work all the time?

Edit:
I was doing something wrong before calling this method. it works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you have var = yourvar; you would use print yourvar.toString(); without argument.

Comment: yes but I'm not trying to print I'm trying to get the result in another variable so I use the static method of the class. but it don't work right I need another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to convert a Unicode character represented by an decimal or hex integer into a Java String in Android:

---

I use `Character.toString()` to convert unicode integer/hex values to String characters. This example converts the unicode value for the Up Arrow character into a String.

Up Arrow example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:U%2B2191.svg

```
final int upSymbolUnicode = 0x2191;
final String text = Character.toString((char)upSymbolUnicode);
```

I hope this helps.